# How to change NCLOB to NVARCHAR2(150 CHAR) via DevArt using code first?

Tags: oracle, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, devart

Googling 2-nd day and figure out that can't find how to convert NCLOB to NVARCHAR2(150 CHAR) using DevArt and Code First approach in .NET & Oracle.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

If the column already exists in database, refer to https://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?t=32547 .

In case of the newly created columns, you can either specify MaxLength for each string property or set config.CodeFirstOptions.[UseNonLobStrings](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?CodeFirstOptions.html)=true.